# AddressVerify API — do not have permissions to make this API call

Tags: php, paypal

I have called AddressVerify API of PayPal in sandbox mode but it returns with error,

```
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Authentication/Authorization Failed
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => You do not have permissions to make this API call
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
```

My code for AddressVerification is,

```
function verify_address($PayPalConfig, $email, $street, $zipcode) {

    $PayPal = new PayPal($PayPalConfig);

    $AVFields = array(
        'EMAIL' => $email,
        'STREET' => $street,
        'ZIP' => $zipcode,
    );

    $PayPalRequestData = array(
        'AVFields' => $AVFields,            
    );

    $PayPalResult = $PayPal->AddressVerify($PayPalRequestData);
    return $PayPalResult;

}
```

I want to know is there any setting to enable this API Call or any other method which will call this api successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Address Verification is normally not enabled with sandbox. So, you will need to open a support request or make phone call to enable that.